Не работает терминал в PyChar: Cannot open Local Failed to start [powershell.exe, -NoExit, -ExecutionPolicy, Bypass, -File,

Cannot open Local
Failed to start [powershell.exe, -NoExit, -ExecutionPolicy, Bypass, -File, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.1.4 ...
See IDE log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.
